# How to get device ID of sensor tag cc2650 (BLE) IOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

For integration we are trying to identify each BLE device uniquely when device is scanned from IOS and Android .

we are getting following information of BLE device when we scan device from Android and IOS.

Android :

Device ID : B0:B4:48:C8:66:82
                   B0:B4:48:C8:77:82

---

IOS :

Device ID :  iPHone - 6

```
"9CDEF5C0-6F20-7849-2670-323E3052822C",
"7627B0D4-DF20-815C-2984-A4AF4B413C3A"

 iPHone 5

"8501DC03-D0E7-B2E8-5877-70F9BFCDC0E5",
"8501DC03-D0E7-B2E8-5877-70F9BFCDC0E5"
```

We are not able to get unique identifier when BLE device scan from IOS application. We are getting device identifier but its not constant for each device.

Please advice how we can identify BLE device uniquely from Android and IOS application.

Comment: What do you mean with BLE device? The build in bluetooth module of the phone or an external bluetooth device connected to your phone.

Comment: external bluetooth device  sensor tag cc2650